# How to Manage Session in side menu in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

`Ionic app` with a `side menu`

Here my app concept is **Blog App** 
in this I need to log-in, profile, etc
`Ionic app` with a `side menu` 
if user want to like or comment any blog post he must log-in first

so I want to manage session if the already log-in user so hide log-in `ion-item` from side menu else logout `ion-item` vise-Versa

Here is code

**home.html**

```
   <ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content" >

    <ion-menu  contentId="main-content" >
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar  color="primary">

          <ion-title>Lady Help Lady</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>

      <ion-content color="primary">
        <ion-list >
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
            <ion-item color="primary" [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon" color="light"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label color="light">
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>

          </ion-menu-toggle>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" >
            <ion-item color="primary"  *ngIf="showBtnLogin"> 
                <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-in" color="light"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label color="light" (click)="login()">
                   Login
                </ion-label>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item color="primary"  *ngIf="!showBtnLogin">
                <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-out" color="light"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label color="light" (click)="logout()" > Log Out</ion-label>
            </ion-item>

   </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>

    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>


</ion-app>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { StorageService } from '../services/storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Blog',
      url: '/home/blog',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'Profile',
      url: '/home/profile',
      icon: 'cog'
    },
    {
      title: 'Change Password',
      url: '/home/change-password',
      icon: 'lock'
    },

    {
      title: 'About Us',
      url: '/home/about-us',
      icon: 'cog'
    },
    {
      title: 'Privacy Policy',
      url: '/home/privacy-policy',
      icon: 'settings'
    }
    ,
    {
      title: 'Terms & Conditions',
      url: '/home/terms-conditions',
      icon: 'paper'
    },
    {
      title: 'Enable Location',
      url: '/home/enable-location',
      icon: 'pin'
    }
    ,
    {
      title: 'Donation',
      url: '/home/donation',
      icon: 'card'
    }


  ];
  public authUser: any;
  showBtnLogin = true;
  // showBtnLogout: boolean = true;
 currentUser: any;
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService, 
              private menu: MenuController, 
              public storageService: StorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.authService.userData$.subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.authUser = res;
       if (res === null) {
         console.log(res);
         this.showBtnLogin = false;
       } else {
        this.showBtnLogin = true;
       }  
     });
  }
  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
  login() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home/login']);
  }


}
```

login.page.ts

```
validateInputs() {
    const mobile = this.postData.mobile.trim();
    const password = this.postData.password.trim();
    return (
      this.postData.mobile &&
      this.postData.password &&
      mobile.length > 0 &&
      password.length > 0
    );
  }

  formLogin() {
    if (this.validateInputs()) {
      this.loader.loadingPresent();
      console.log(this.postData);
      this.authService.login(this.postData).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          if (res.status === true) {
            this.loader.loadingDismiss();
            // Storing the User data.
            this.storageService.store(AuthConstants.AUTH, res.logindata);
            this.router.navigate(['/home/blog']);
          } else {
            this.loader.loadingDismiss();
            this.toastService.presentToast(res.error);
          }
        },
        (error: any) => {
          this.loader.loadingDismiss();
          this.toastService.presentToast('Network Issue.');
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.loader.loadingDismiss();
      this.toastService.presentToast('Please enter mobile or password.');
    }
  }
```

StorageService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Storage } = Plugins;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StorageService {

  constructor() { }
  // Store the value
async store(storageKey: string, value: any) {
  const encryptedValue = btoa(escape(JSON.stringify(value)));
  await Storage.set({
  key: storageKey,
  value: encryptedValue
  });
  }

  // Get the value
  async get(storageKey: string) {
  const ret = await Storage.get({ key: storageKey });
  return JSON.parse(unescape(atob(ret.value)));
  }

  async removeStorageItem(storageKey: string) {
  await Storage.remove({ key: storageKey });
  }

  // Clear storage
  async clear() {
  await Storage.clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do that like this 
in your html

```
 <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" >
          <ion-item color="primary"  *ngIf="showBtnLogin"> 
              <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-in" color="light"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label color="light" (click)="login()">
                 Login
              </ion-label>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item color="primary"  *ngIf="!showBtnLogin">
              <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-out" color="light"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label color="light" (click)="logout()" > Log Out</ion-label>
          </ion-item>

 </ion-menu-toggle>
```

in your .ts

```
showBtnLogin: boolean = true;
currentUser: any;

ngOnInit() { 
    this.authService.userData$.subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.authUser = res;
      // this.postData.user_id = res.id;
      console.log(this.authUser.id);
      this.currentUser =  this.authUser;
       if (res === null) {
         this.showBtnLogin = true;
       } else {
        this.showBtnLogin = false;
       }  
     });
}

logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
}

login() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home/login']);
}
```

Comment: are you understand what exactly my project flow

Comment: can you share two files with me? i will solve your problem

Comment: if user login then profiles, change password, will be shown and logout also
or if user not logged in then hide all above options only login will be available

Answer (score 1):

Change some code in your .ts file here it is

```
  showBtnLogin = true;
  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Blog',
      url: '/home/blog',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'Profile',
      url: '/home/profile',
      icon: 'cog',
      status: true
    },
    {
      title: 'Change Password',
      url: '/home/change-password',
      icon: 'lock',
      status: true
    },

    {
      title: 'About Us',
      url: '/home/about-us',
      icon: 'cog',
      status: true
    },
    {
      title: 'Privacy Policy',
      url: '/home/privacy-policy',
      icon: 'settings',
      status: true
    }
    ,
    {
      title: 'Terms & Conditions',
      url: '/home/terms-conditions',
      icon: 'paper',
      status: true
    },
    {
      title: 'Enable Location',
      url: '/home/enable-location',
      icon: 'pin',
      status: true
    }
    ,
    {
      title: 'Donation',
      url: '/home/donation',
      icon: 'card',
      status: true
    }
  ];
```

In your ngOnInit

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.userData$.subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.authUser = res;
      if (res === null) {
        console.log(res);
        this.showBtnLogin = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.appPages.length; i++) {
          if (this.appPages[i].title == 'Profile') {
            this.appPages[i].status = false;
          }
          if (this.appPages[i].title == 'Change Password') {
            this.appPages[i].status = false;
          }
        }
      } else {
        this.showBtnLogin = true;
      }
    });
  }
```

if your profile and change password index not change then you can directly change status via index without using for loop

and finally in your logout

```
  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.appPages.length; i++) {
      if (this.appPages[i].title == 'Profile') {
        this.appPages[i].status = false;
      }
      if (this.appPages[i].title == 'Change Password') {
        this.appPages[i].status = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

In your .html file

```
<ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]" *ngIf="p.status">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
            <ion-item color="primary" *ngIf="showBtnLogin">
              <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-in" color="light"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label color="light" (click)="login()">
                Login
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item color="primary" *ngIf="!showBtnLogin">
              <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-out" color="light"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label color="light" (click)="logout()"> Log Out</ion-label>
            </ion-item>

          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
```

Comment: Sry but it is still not working any other way to do please let me know it is urgent

Comment: Can you check your auth service? Console your auth service data or debug your code cause this code is working when i manually set showbtnlogin true or false

Comment: Yes manually it is working also getting value in log if user logged in

Comment: You can save your user data in localstorage for checking user is logged in or not

Comment: I have update 2 more files login.ts and StorageService.ts